# how to unregistre jquery mmenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I am using jquery mmenu in my webpage for mobile device and desktop resolutions minor than 1024. In desktop, I am using a function to check resolution on page load and resize, if window is minor than 1000px mmenu is activated.

My problem is when I want to resize the page to window size major to 1000px, the mmenu has removed my normal navigation and not showed in the page any more.

How to unregistre mmenu and restore my first state navigation menu?

This is my function:

```
if($(window).width()<1000){
    $("#webNav").mmenu();
    var API = $("#webNav").data( "mmenu" );

    $("#open-mobile").click(function() {
        API.open();
    });
}
```

Comment: just add an else! :) but also assign a arable accessor to `$("#webNav").mmenu()`

Comment: Sorry @Pogrindis I don't understand you, can you clarify your point?.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, you can wrap it inside a resize event listener..

```
//We keep a reference to the menu object outside the scope of the event check. 
$("#webNav").mmenu();
var API = $("#webNav").data( "mmenu" );

//When a resize occurs, it will run the following. 
$(window).resize(function () { 
   if($(window).width()<1000){
      $("#open-mobile").click(function() {
        API.open();
      });
   }
   else{ // Otherwise we remove the reference to what `data` is. 
   API = $("#webNav").data("");
   }
});
```

This will run your piece of logic every time you resize the screen..

I havent tested this but it should work, you may need to clear the events after the screen increases but let me know and I can update it.

On the larger size, it resets the same reference to the API object..

`$("#webNav").data("");`

This should clear out the object itself.